# Ruby on Rails - Transactions - Generating X amount of codes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I run this code on create:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
   5.times { Vouchercode.create(Vouchercode_params) }
end
```

Which creates 5 voucher codes - this works as I expect. What I want to do is to allow my users to enter a number themselves.

for example:

A user enters 25 into a form and 25 vouchers are generated.

How could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this code in your controller or model?

Regardless, pass the number to the controller using a form parameter like `n_vouchers` and replace `5` with `params[:n_vouchers].to_i`.

Note that if they input nothing or a letter, they will get 0 vouchers because `.to_i` will result in 0.

Comment: Controller, Thanks it works perfectly. I will add validation using JavaScript to help prevent a result of 0

Comment: @Stefano JavaScript validation should always be complemented by server-side validation. Be wary.